# Is there a way to execute C# script in sharepoint online?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, aspose, powerapps

I have an aspose library with which I want to execute some commands e.g Make PDF from images, send email etc.

I use sharepoint to store images from an app. This app is made by Powerapps.

So what I basically want is to use the Aspose library to do some functions, but it is not available for sharepoint online.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I am afraid Aspose.Pdf for SharePoint may not be used for SharePoint online, at the moment. However, a feature request with ID **PDFSP-33391** is already logged into our issue management system for implementation of this feature. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have the Azure subscription, you can create an Azure function and use that with powerapps (creating a custom API and then utilizing).